# how assign value in set() Object.create

Tags: javascript

I create object with object.create and necessary set value + 5 to current property

```
const obj = Object.create({}, {
  addFive: {
    set(value) {
     //???
     }
   }
})
```

I need next implementation:

```
obj.addFive = 1
console.log(obj.addFive)
6
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your [setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) `addFive` you can keep the value in a separate property `_value` and then update it like:

```
set(value) {
  this._value = value + 5;
}
```

You will also need a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) for this so that you can retrieve the value when you call `console.log(obj.addFive)` like:

```
get() {
  return this._value;
}
```

DEMO:

```js
const obj = Object.create({}, {
  addFive: {
    get() {
      return this._value;
    },
    set(value) {
      this._value = value + 5;
    }
  }
})

obj.addFive = 1
console.log(obj.addFive)
```

Comment: This also creates a public *_value* property. It might be better to use [*Object.defineProperty*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to set appropriate descriptor values, such as *enumerable* and *configurable*. :-)

Comment: Yes, that can be also done, but I just wanted to keep the example simple for start.

Comment: If if i do this i have a new property in object. I can assign value to property addFive?